# Matching and Counting Strings of Characters in R

Tags: r, string, character

I have an array of strings of characters made up of all the possible combinations of the 4 letters `J, K, Q, Z`. The entries in the array are made up of at least two letters and at most 4. For example: `data<-c("QK", "KQ", "JKQZ", "KJZ")`.

I would like to count the number of times each entry in the array occurs but without differentiating between strings that are made up of the same letters but in different order. I know `table(data)` doesn't do this since it doesn't think of `QK` and `KQ` as the same and returns

```
data
JKQZ  KJZ   KQ   QK 
   1    1    1    1
```

I have been looking at `pmatch` or `charmatch` but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

EDIT: I should clarify that there are no entries in which a letter is repeated. In essence, I cannot have an entry `ZZ` or `KZK`

Comment: Here's an awkword possible solution `table(sapply(strsplit(data, ""), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "")))`

Comment: So, basically, it rewrites each entry in alphabetical order and then uses table(), correct?

Comment: Yeah, something like that...

Comment: Would "QQQ" go in it's own bucket, or aggregated with "Q" ?

Comment: I should clarify that repetitions of letters in the same entry are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first make a table per observation (set as a factor to get the zero cells), then hash each table and count that:

```
require(magrittr)
require(digest)
data<-c("QK", "KQ", "JKQZ", "KJZ")
tbl <- strsplit(data, "") %>% lapply(factor,levels=c("K","Q", "J", "Z")) %>%
lapply(table) %>%  do.call(what=rbind)
tbl
```

which gives this:

```
     K Q J Z
[1,] 1 1 0 0
[2,] 1 1 0 0
[3,] 1 1 1 1
[4,] 1 0 1 1
```

Then hash and count:

```
h <- apply(tbl, 1, digest)
tbl <- cbind(tbl, count=as.vector(table(h)[h]))
tbl <- tbl[!duplicated(h), ]
```

Here's the result:

```
     K Q J Z count
[1,] 1 1 0 0     2
[2,] 1 1 1 1     1
[3,] 1 0 1 1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a longer variation on David's comment/answer:

```
vals    <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(data,''))))
combos  <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(vals),function(i)combn(vals,i,paste0,collapse="")))
newdata <- factor(sapply(strsplit(data,""),function(x)paste0(sort(x),collapse="")),
             levels=combos)
tab <- table(newdata)
# newdata
#    J    K    Q    Z   JK   JQ   JZ   KQ   KZ   QZ  JKQ  JKZ  JQZ  KQZ JKQZ 
#    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    1    0    0    1 
tab[tab>0] # alternately
#   KQ  JKZ JKQZ 
#    2    1    1
```